# R: LiblineaR package

Tags: r, regression, regularized

I am using the LiblineaR package on R to do an L1-Regression. However, it seems to return a slightly different model every time I run it. Is this supposed to be non-deterministic?

```
reg = LiblineaR(data = df, target = response, type = 6, cost = 0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The LiblineaR package is a wrapper around the LIBLINEAR C/C++ library for
machine learning. The LIBLINEAR C/C++ library has its own random number generator and no way to seed it from the public C API (so the differences you're seeing are normal behavior and should be expected)